# How to fill randomly chosen object of class with random generated parameters?

Tags: java, random, generator

I have to change my code to solution from using reflection to generation random parameters.

I couldn't figure out how to made this implementation...

Here is class generator:

```
public class SweetsGenerator implements Generator<Sweets>, Iterable<Sweets> {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SweetsGenerator.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Class[] types = { 
        WhiteChocolate.class, MilkChokolate.class,  DarkChocolate.class, 
        DesertChocolate.class, PorousChocolate.class, 
    };

    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public SweetsGenerator() {
    }

    private int size = 0;

    public SweetsGenerator(int sz) {
        size = sz;
    }

    public Sweets next() {
        try {
            return (Sweets) types[rand.nextInt(types.length)].newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("RuntimeException", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    class SweetsIterator implements Iterator<Sweets> {
        int count = size;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return count > 0;
        }

        public Sweets next() {
            count--;
            return SweetsGenerator.this.next();
        }

        public void remove() { // Not implemented
            LOG.error("UnsupportedOperationException");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };

    public Iterator<Sweets> iterator() {
        return new SweetsIterator();
    }
}
```

How to circumvent this approach and create new class element, for example as:

> new WhiteChocolate((rand.nextDouble() * 100) + 1, (rand.nextDouble() * 200) + 1);

I can't it combine with randomise generation class witch element we can create.

Here is content of `Sweets` abstract class and one of it implementation:

```
public abstract class Sweets {

    private double sugarLevel;

    private double weight;

    public double getSugarLevel() {
        return sugarLevel;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setSugarLevel(double sugarLevel) {
        this.sugarLevel = sugarLevel;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + sugarLevel + " " + weight);
        return sb.toString();
    }   
}

public class Chocolate extends Sweets {

    public Chocolate() {
    }

    public Chocolate(double aSugarLevel, double aWeight) {
        setSugarLevel(aSugarLevel);
        setWeight(aWeight);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to modify `next()` by ***skiwi*** suggestion.

Changed version is next:

```
public Sweets next() {
    Sweets current = instances[rand.nextInt(instances.length)];
    Double param1 = (rand.nextDouble() * 100) + 1;
    Double param2 = (rand.nextDouble() * 200) + 1;
    System.out.println("parameters: " + Math.round(param1) + " " + Math.round(param2));

    try {
        return (Sweets) current.getClass()
                .getConstructor(Double.class, Double.class)
                .newInstance(Math.round(param1), Math.round(param2));
        // Report programmer errors at run time:
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("RuntimeException", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

But it throws next bunch of exceptions:

```
23:25:51,337 ERROR main SweetsGenerator:next:52 - RuntimeException
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.epam.lab.chocolate.DarkChocolate.<init>(java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2800)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1708)
    at com.epam.lab.SweetsGenerator.next(SweetsGenerator.java:48)
    at com.epam.lab.NewYearGift.generate(NewYearGift.java:37)
    at com.epam.lab.GiftList.generateGift(GiftList.java:47)
    at com.epam.lab.GiftList.main(GiftList.java:59)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.epam.lab.chocolate.DarkChocolate.<init>(java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double)
    at com.epam.lab.SweetsGenerator.next(SweetsGenerator.java:53)
    at com.epam.lab.NewYearGift.generate(NewYearGift.java:37)
    at com.epam.lab.GiftList.generateGift(GiftList.java:47)
    at com.epam.lab.GiftList.main(GiftList.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.epam.lab.chocolate.DarkChocolate.<init>(java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2800)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1708)
    at com.epam.lab.SweetsGenerator.next(SweetsGenerator.java:48)
    ... 3 more
```

Solution for this problem was to change one line:

> return (Sweets) current.getClass().getConstructor(double.class, double.class)
>   .newInstance(Math.round(param1), Math.round(param2));

***How to safe this logic of generator and create randomly elements with parameters?***

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a constructor contract like `public WhiteChololate(Double a, Double b)`, you can call the following to create a new instance:

```
Double a = 1d;
Double b = 2d;
WhiteChocolate.class.getConstructor(Double.class, Double.class).newInstance(a, b);
```

This will construct the required instance, not ethat I am using this syntax over `Class<?>.newInstance()`, since as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29):

> **Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler. The Constructor.newInstance method avoids this problem by wrapping any exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked) InvocationTargetException.**

So using `Constructor.newInstance(...)` is both more safe and is the only one that will satisfy your needs.

Note that you need to specify the parameters **type** in the `.getConstructor()` call and not the value yet.

Comment: @nazar_art Your `DarkChocolate` has no constructor that takes `Double, Double`. All classes need to take that constructor, or you'd need to make some distinction in your generator's `next()`.

Comment: Solution was change to `getConstructor(double.class, double.class)`